# How to change the name of thread group in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm pretty much new to multithreading, so the question I'm going to ask could be simple.

In my program, there are two threads, one is **main** thread and the second one is **mythread**.

```
package multithreading;

public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        new MyThread();
        try {
            for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {                             
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread() {     
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("mythread");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                //System.out.println("MyThread i value "+i);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the output of program is,

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[mythread,5,main]
```

I know what the output means.

But I want to change the thread group of **mythread** to my own rather than **main**.
How can I do this?

What Java method is used to change the thread group of  a thread?

Would be there any issues by changing the thread group?

Comment: also dont invoke `start()` from thread's constructor.. the user of your thread might not be aware of the fact that, construction of `MyThread` actually starts it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest implementing Runnable instead of extending Thread. You can then easily create a new thread with its own group:

```
public class ThreadDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        Runnable r = new MyRunnable();
        new Thread(new ThreadGroup("my group"), r).start();
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("mythread");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                //System.out.println("MyThread i value "+i);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create your own ThreadGroup and use Thread(ThreadGroup group, String name) constructor to create a Thread:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(ThreadGroup tg, String name) {
        super(tg, name);
        start();
    }

...

ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup("mythreadgroup");
new MyThread(tg, "mythread");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread has a constructor which allows you to set a ThreadGroup:

`Thread(ThreadGroup group, String name)`

So if you would change the constructor like this:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(ThreadGroup group) {
        // We set the name here instead.
        super(group, "mythread");          
        start();
    }
}
```

Then create the thread like this:

```
public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("mythread");
        new MyThread(threadGroup);
        try {
            for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {                             
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A thread group is basically a convenience for collecting threads and then being able to perform operations on all of them, such as `interrupt()` and limiting priorities set to the threads.

But if all you want to do is to change the `toString()` of MyThread, then you could simply override toString() instead - that would be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

some more info:
ThreadGroup is a class in java and every Thread in java have some ThreadGroup, to check ThreadGroup parent name use

> `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getParent().getName();`

for example ThreadGroup of main thread is > `system`
We can create our own ThreadGroup as

> `ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("myCustomThreadGroup");`

In above example,

```
public class ThreadDemo 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getParent().getName()); // system
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()); // Thread[main,5,main]
    ThreadGroup threadGroupName = new ThreadGroup("MyOwnThreadGroup"); // create ThreadGroup
    new MyThread(threadGroupName, "myCustThread1"); // create Thread   
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
 MyThread(ThreadGroup threadGroupName, String threadName) 
 {
    super(threadGroupName, threadName);
    start();
 }
 public void run() 
 {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()); //Thread[myCustThread1,5,MyOwnThreadGroup]
 }
}
```